# add option to login using twitter, facebook and google using socialauth on android app

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, socialauth

I am building an app that connects to a website to fetch data. A login screen is provided that gives the option of logging in using the site username and password or using social apps like facebook, twitter and google. The buttons for which are provided. I have downloaded socialauth library to use with the app. I followed https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/ for instructions on how to use the library. But the documentation is rather sketchy. Any help on how to use the library will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
What mainly I want to do is to provide the login facility of facebook, google and twitter to log into my app just like the feature provided on many web sites and apps.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am putting here code..Hope it will help you..
Note: You need to put oath_consumer.properties in your assets folder as well as add socialauth library in your project.

```
   public class ClientLogin extends Activity {
TextView facebookLogin,TwitterLogin,LinkedInLogin;
     SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
     Button logout;
 Context context;
 Profile profileMap;
 String Email,password;
     String provider_Name;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.client_login);
    context=this;
    facebookLogin=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_LoginFacebook);
    TwitterLogin=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_LoginTwitter);
    LinkedInLogin=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_LoginLinkedin);
  logout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_loginLogout);
 adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
    facebookLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            provider_Name="facebook";
            adapter.authorize(context, Provider.FACEBOOK);

        }
    });
       TwitterLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            provider_Name="twitter";
            adapter.authorize(context, Provider.TWITTER);

        }
    });
    LinkedInLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
    provider_Name="linkedin";
        adapter.authorize(context, Provider.LINKEDIN);

        }
    });
     logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stubadapter.
           adapter.signOut(context, Provider.FACEBOOK.toString())   ;
           adapter.signOut(context, Provider.LINKEDIN.toString())   ;
           adapter.signOut(context, Provider.TWITTER.toString())    ;
         Toast.makeText(context,"succesfully Logged out",1000).show();

        }
    });
    }

      private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener 
{
     public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
          //  Log.d("ShareButton" , "Authentication Successful");
         Toast.makeText(context,"succesfully Logged in",1000).show();

        //code  is to get email id of user...
         profileMap =  adapter.getUserProfile();

         if (provider_Name.equalsIgnoreCase("facebook"))
                 {
           //to get email_id of user..

        Email=profileMap.getEmail();

                 }
         else if( provider_Name.equalsIgnoreCase("twitter"))
         {

            //to get email of user
            Email=profileMap.getEmail(); 


         }
    else  if (provider_Name.equalsIgnoreCase("linkedin"))
         {



Email=profileMap.getEmail();

         }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Kirti..Please tell me how to implement sign in with google account in android, as facebook login with new popup window...

Comment: @Srinivasan  Hi, You can do sign in with Google account by using same library i.e socialauth by writting  adapter.authorize(context, Provider.GOOGLEPLUS); or if you want to do by using googlePLus library then for that you can refer the link :https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in. Thanks

Comment: I checked the mentioned link,but I want to authenticate the user every time as like login with facebook .But in this case if we implement the google api client,It will connect automatically on get connected whenever we come to this activity